# Confusing message from new review queue?

Tags: bug, comments, review, community-user

The [answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/662283/81133) (in which a new user posted an elaboration on their question as an answer) has the following comment from the Community bot, presumably due to its review in the new "First Answers" queue (bolding mine):

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, **such as working code or documentation citations.**

I assume this message is fine for the Stack Overflow mother ship, but it doesn't seem quite right for us.

Can this message be changed?  Suggestions:

1. Simply eliminate the second clause, so it just reads "Please add further details to expand on your answer."
2. Revert the message to what it was under the "First Posts" queue.  (I can't recall what that exact phrasing was, though.)

Other suggestions are, of course, welcome.

Also, does the new "First Questions" queue have similar software-centric automated messages that need to be modified?

Comment: Here's a post specifically complaining about this issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369111/334566

Comment: Mike, besides the thread on the main Meta, there have been complaints about these features of the new reviewing messages on quite a few sites' own meta sites.  I'm hoping that the evident issues will gradually get cleaned up.